# SPARQL query doesn't return results

Tags: sparql, ontology, protege

I have created an ontology using Protege and am trying to create queries using SPARQL. I created this query to get the name of all parents:

```
    PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
    PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
    PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    PREFIX dc:<http://www.semanticweb.org/me/ontologies/2021/11/untitled-ontology-3#>
    SELECT DISTINCT ?nmParents
        WHERE { ?uriParents dc:parentOf  ?uriEnfants.
                ?uriParents dc:name ?nmParents.
               }
```

But this query doesn't return any results although the ontology is well created and this query returns results:

```
    SELECT ?n
    WHERE { ?uriP dc:name ?n.}
```

Any suggestions??

Comment: the query looks ok at a first glance, **but**: without seeing sample RDF data how do you think anybody can tell why the result is empty? Please show sample RDF data (in RDF syntax please, ideally Turtle or N-Triples) - thank you?

Comment: If you really have a property `parentOf`, did you assign those facts explicitly, or do you have another relation `childOf` and used this to assert the facts and just declared `parentOf` as the inverse relation of `childOf`? If so, you'd need a reasoning capable SPARQL engine, in Protege this only works with the SNAP SPARQL plugin

Comment: Yes i have an object property "parentOf" and its inverse "childOf" and i'm using FaCT++ reasoner.

Comment: I noticed that queries using just Data properties like name, age, ...return results but queries using object properties like parentOf, childOf,.. don't return any results

Comment: read my second comment. If in your data you use `childOf` for the explciit facts, you need a SPARQL engine that makes use of reasoning. The standard SPARQL tab in Protege does **not** do this. You have to use the SNAP SPARQL plugin

Comment: `Window -> Views -> Query Views -> Snap SPARQL Query` is what you have to use for SPARQL combined with reasoning

Comment: How to add Snap SPARQL plugin ??

Comment: if it's not already installed, via the plugins menu section of course. `File ->`

Comment: when i click on check for plugins i got a message "no additional plugins/updates available at this time". I'm using Protege 4.3 version

Comment: try version 5.5.0 or is there a reason for using such an old version?

Comment: I'm a student and our teacher tell us to use this version.

Comment: I see, but this is an years old version of a tool which has been changed a lot in the meantime. I cannot help here, I can just tell you that you will need the Snap SPARQL plugin and I doubt this will work on the old 4.3.0 version.